# Disordered GUI formatting

Tags: maven, swing, formatting, jframe, netbeans-13

I'm creating a GUI in NetBeans 13 using Java Swing and Maven as my Built Tool, and I'm about to finish up when I noticed that my GUI formatting got disorganized.

I'm gonna send a picture of what my JFrame form should look like and the disordered one to further clarify my question.

[How it initially looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1nIP.jpg)

[The disordered version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7Q2s.jpg)

I have a total of four JFrame Forms, namely, `Final_Frame`, `Log_In`, `Register`, and `Loading_screen`(my main class). Everything is working perfectly fine when I tried to run my project starting from `Log_In` to `Final_Frame`, `Register` to `Final_Frame`, or `Log_in` to `Register` to `Final_Frame`. But when I tried to add `Loading_screen` at the very start since this is my main class, although it doesn't affect the GUI format of my `Log_In` and/or `Register`, it started to affect the GUI formatting of my `Final_Frame`. I also don't know how my `Loading_screen` affected `Final_Frame` since my `Loading_screen` only has a couple of `JPanel`, `JLabel`, and a `Progress Bar`

I couldn't figure out the problem at all since it is not throwing an `Exception` so I tried to `Clean` my project and then `Build` again but the problem still occurs.

Hope you can help me, thank you so much.

Comment: _when I tried to add `Loading_screen` at the very start_ So you changed your code and started seeing problems, right? That implies to me that the cause of your problem may be the code. Forgive me, but unless I see your code, I can't help you with it. Just out of curiosity, what kind of answer were you expecting to get? Something regarding how to configure Maven or NetBeans? I suggest that you [edit] your question and post a [mcve]. Also add the platform you are on and the Java version you are using.

Comment: @Abra Good day! First of all, thank you for responding. So I figured out that the problem lies with the type of `FlatLaf` theme that I'm using, I'm using the `FlatDarkLaf` theme in my `Final_Frame`, `Log_In`, and `Register` which differs from the `FlatDarculaLaf` theme that I'm using in my `Loading_screen`, and that what's causing the problem. Thank you so much and I will definitely consider your suggestion when I try to ask a question again, thanks!

Comment: @Abra So then I tried to make all of their themes to `FlatDarkLaf` and then they worked. So I guess if I have multiple JFrame from then I should use the same `FlatLaf` theme.